# Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath is not defined by "exports"

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, package.json, es6-modules

`Node.js` 16.14.2, `npm` 8.19.2.

I am trying to run a simple `Node.js` script that imports `OrbitDB`. Here is the script:

*`hello_orbitdb.js`*

```
// import the package
const OrbitDB = require('orbit-db');
```

Here is how I am trying to run it, and the error I am getting:

```
$ node hello_orbitdb.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:488
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './cid' is not defined by "exports" in /node_modules/multiformats/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:453:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:671:7)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/orbit-db/src/orbit-db-address.js:3:17) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
```

So I took a look at `/node_modules/orbit-db/src/orbit-db-address.js` and here is how it starts:

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const { CID } = require('multiformats/cid')
```

**How can I correct this error?**

In my `node_modules` folder, there are

```
  "name": "orbit-db",
  "version": "0.28.7",
```

and

```
  "name": "multiformats",
  "version": "10.0.2",
```

Comment: Very strange, i have exactly the same node, npm & orbit-db packa and haven't the errors.

Have you try deleting node_module directory and do a `npm install` again?

Comment: Can you please check on your machine and let me know which multiformats version you have installed there? Is your version of multiformats a CommonJS module, or does it at least support also CommonJS?

Comment: My multiformats version is `9.9.0` I think you have a dependence conflict

Comment: After seeing [this](https://github.com/orbitdb/orbit-db/commit/be4f31d25a36edcb4744c2d7d2892eaf061a2e7d) commit adding `multiformats` as a dependency and then requiring it directly in a module, followed by [this](https://github.com/orbitdb/orbit-db/commit/ff101db5442ccf99ba79fccb5682aafbf9496c0b) commit on the same day removing `multiformats` as a dependency but not removing the require from the module, you should think twice about using `orbit-db`, IMO. They are using transitive dependencies as direct dependencies.

Answer (score 10):

You problem sound like a dependance problem.

First, try to delete node_modules directory and issue a `npm install` in order to re import dependencies.

If problem persist, issue a `npm install --save multiformats@9.9.0` and see if this correct your problem or not.

Comment: I think the problem is what I suspected it was when I posted my first question for you. But you are suggesting to delete `node_modules` that may provide modules for numerous other projects, and then run `npm install` - but from which directory? And would it not require me to do a lot of quite manual reinstalling in order to restore the current  `node_modules`?

Comment: Normally not if everything was done in state of art!

Normally you should have a package.json file in the same directory 

Issuing a `npm install`will reintall all dependencies list in package.json
if some depencecies have been installed without `--save` option you effectively have to reinstall manually one by one these packages

Comment: If you prefer, just rename node_module to node_module.old. In case of problems, you can restore it. You can also skip the node_module step and directly reinstall multiformats 9.9.0

Comment: Thanks! I thought removing the whole node_modules was an overkill. So I just installed multiformats@9.9.0 and it allowed `require('orbit-db')` to run (as CommonJS script). That automatically removed multiformats@10.0.2 and replaced it with 9.9.0. But of course that made other ES scripts that import multiformats@10.0.2 to fail. Is there any way to install in node_modules and then load more than one version of a module?

Comment: That's what I feared! Multiformats is required by others package you use.
So, you have one way resolving this, i mean finding the less bad solution.

You need to find the lowest common denominator for package version that solve the dependencies problem

Comment: You can also try to contact mainainers of orbit-db package to ask us solve problem with multifomats or you can submius a pull request yourself. But this can take some time to be accepted or not.

Comment: There is a suggestion in morganney's answer, to replace `const { CID } = require('multiformats/cid')` with `const { CID } = import('multiformats/cid')`. It also works. I am not very familiar with Node.js. From what I see, the system is not very stable and well-designed. Not a lot of thought was devoted to code readability, consistency, reliability and maintainability. The module management and loading system is poorly designed.

Comment: Here is something strange. It seems like I need a system like OrbitDB, which happens to be written for Node.js. But most Node modules cannot run on a browser as is. They need node.js to be installed. So why writing them in this mixture of JS dialects which is hard to maintain? It would be easier to write back-end modules in a language and environment that have better back-end support. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Your primary issue is that `orbit-db` depends upon `multiformats` which has been an ES Module since [`v1.0.0`](https://github.com/multiformats/js-multiformats/blob/v1.0.0/package.json#L6), but the source code for `orbit-db` that you showed has

```js
const { CID } = require('multiformats/cid')
```

and ES modules can only be loaded inside of CommonJS modules via dynamic `import()` statements. See the Node.js documentation on ES module [interoperability with CommonJS modules in regards to `require`](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#require).

> Using require to load an ES module is not supported because ES modules have asynchronous execution. Instead, use import() to load an ES module from a CommonJS module.

You would have to open a PR that updates the `require` to a dynamic `import('multiformats/cid')`. The best location would probably be [in this `try` block](https://github.com/orbitdb/orbit-db/blob/main/src/orbit-db-address.js#L39-L45), but then you would be changing the API for the `static isValid` method from synchronous to asynchronous. Not a huge effort, [doesn't appear to be used in many locations](https://github.com/orbitdb/orbit-db/search?q=isValid) and the API seems to be internal, i.e. not public facing.

Still, you might prefer the easier route and downgrade your version of `orbit-db` to `v0.26.0` which [uses](https://github.com/orbitdb/orbit-db/blob/v0.26.0/src/orbit-db-address.js#L3) the older [`cids`](https://github.com/multiformats/js-cid) package which is CommonJS.

Update your package.json entry for `orbit-db`:

```json
"orbit-db": "^0.26.0"
```

Reinstall:

```
npm i
```

Comment: I'm not so familiar with node.js. But it's strange, after I installed multiformats@9.9.0, I looked at its package.json in my local node_modules and it did not have "type": "module" (as opposed to what you may see on Github), so it seems to be a CommonJs module on my machine. And indeed it worked with orbit-db 0.28.7 which loads it with `require`.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about the import() thing. It managed to hide itself in the documentation. The rest was not so clear to me. "ES modules have asynchronous execution" - but we are loading them, not yet executing them. And are they saying that in ES modules, every method that uses other loaded modules must be async? I just replaced `const { CID } = require('multiformats/cid')` with `const { CID } = import('multiformats/cid')` in line 3 of orbit-db-address.js, and it seems to run without errors, does it not contradict what you wrote?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with Langchain.js while including different dependencies.I was following a youtube tutorial and that tutorial gave me wrong dependencies and hence I was facing the issue.So try to look depeer into the subpaths and check that whether the subpaths belong to that dependency or not

```
import { HNSWLib } from "@langchain/community/vectorstores/hnswlib";
import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from "@langchain/openai";
import { RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter} from 'langchain/text_splitter';
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was IDE auto import issue

Instead of

```
import {getFirestore} from "firebase-admin/firestore";
```

IDE imported

```
import {getFirestore} from "firebase-admin/lib/firestore";
```

Error

```
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/firestore' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/gyerts/WebstormProjects/apps/starsflow.com/firebase/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

In mine there was a line in the code that I don't remember putting in and that was the cause of this problem.

```js
const { underscoredIf } = require('sequelize/types/utils');
```

probably vscode correct something I typed and this line appears.